# trying to remove kitchen sink, can’t stop water flow

Tags: kitchen-sink

I need to remove a kitchen table top and seems kitchen sink needs to be moved with it.

I tried to cut the water supply but I only see one valve? under the boiler in the pic.  If I turn it the hot water gets reduced 93% but it still runs as you can see in the pic with tap water flow.

Also the cold water completely stays on.

How to stop cold water and hot water properly?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXIT.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Deleting your own comment - you really don’t want help.

Answer (score 0):

Find the stop tap for the cold supply.

Then drain the hot tap pipe - open the hot tap upstairs and all the water will come out at the lowest open point - such as the kitchen hot tap.

Comment: I see two valves which seem to be the hot and cold feeds to the washing machine.  Other than that in another part of the house I see a 'hot water mains' tape, a 'heating cold feed' and a 'cold service' tap.  I am in the UK so dont know if terminology is different.  is cold service the main cold water supply?  Do I also need to turn the 'hot water mains' off which is different to the one under the sink I already did.

Comment: I know you are in the UK... blindingly obvious that was. So, you should know where the stop cocks are for your house - a common sense thing to find out **before** starting work on water pipes. Once you find the cold supply into the house isolate that one and then deal with the hot side. As there are several systems you need to work out which does what - drawing a diagram may, or may not, help you.